# Webpart to showcase Corporate message with image

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, messagebox

I guess this is simple, yet I m struggling to find a solution.

Please let me know the procedure to get a Web Part in SharePoint 2013 that allows adding corporate message box with an image.

Comment: By "message box", you mean a standard "JavaScript alert"? Or a "SharePoint dialog/lightbox"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the solutions you can implement:

1. Create an Announcements List (OOTB) and add a ImageUrl column to it.
2. Create a Picture Library with a RefId column that will contain the ID of relevant announcement.
3. Modify the New and Edit Form of Announcements list to include a FileUpload control that will upload the Image file browsed by the user to the Picture Library and return the Image Url which will be set in the Announcement ListItem's ImageUrl column.
4. Create a Visual WebPart and add these 3 ASP.Net controls to the User control.
   a. A Label control to contain the Title of Announcement - In JS/C# code, populate this Label's Text property with the Announcement Title column.
   b. A Label control to contain the Description of Announcement - In JS/C# code, populate this Label's Text property with the Announcement Body column.
   c. An Image control which will show the Image relevant to the Announcement - In JS/C# code, populate this Label's Text property with the Announcement ImageUrl column.

Comment: I was watchkng a video on uyoutube n it suggest how to create the stuff.